# Ejecutar Etiqueta Iframe dentro de un Label

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

Su ayuda chic@s, necesito cargar un link de youtube que se encuentra en una tabla dentro de una BD. Quise hacerlo a través de un label para trabajar en el behind de mi código.
Pero no me carga el vídeo solo me carga el link dentro del box donde quiero que se vea el vídeo.

```html
<div class="box box-primary">
                            <div class="box-header with-border">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblTituloVideos" Font-Bold="true" Style="color: #1B406D; font-weight: bold; font-size: large" runat="server">Vídeos EME</asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblVideos" runat="server"><iframe Style="width:100%; height:100%;"/></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

```
AT_Personal videos = new AT_Personal();
        DataTable dtVideos = videos.GetVideos();
        lblVideos.Text = dtVideos.Rows[0]["VideoEME"].ToString();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que version del framework usas?

Comment: Uso la 4.7 con VS 2019

Comment: podrias darme un ejemplo de la url que estas intentando mostrar en el iframe?

Comment: No utilice URL, se la estoy pasando a través del la etiqueta label que está en el aspx.cs

Comment: lblVideos.Text = dtVideos.Rows[0]["VideoEME"].ToString();

Comment: bueno quizas sea porque el iframe no tenga src, realmente no me fije! xD y es por eso que no muestra nada, la otra opcion seria tomar con js el texto dentro de label y crear un elemento dentro del label de tipo iframe al cual se le asigna el texto dentro del label.

Comment: Gracias!!! Si intente hacerlo con js pero no lo hice de esa manera como me guías.

Answer (score 0):

Partamos de la base que un video no se carga en un `IFrame` y mucho menos en un `label`, estos son caminos incorrectos

Usa el componente adecuado, o sea el tag [video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) de html

[Usando audio y video con HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Usando_audio_y_video_con_HTML5)

Bien, conociendo cual es tag de html correcto el tema sera como accederlos desde codigo servidor para asignar el valor de la url

Podrias poner el `runat=server` para accederlo desde codigo servidor en c#

```
<video id="videoEME" runat="server" />
```

entonces desde codigo asignas usando

```
AT_Personal videos = new AT_Personal();
DataTable dtVideos = videos.GetVideos();
videoEME.Attributes["src"] = dtVideos.Rows[0]["VideoEME"].ToString();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Tie